# Oracle 11g: Default to static value when query returns nothing

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Working in Oracle 11g, I have a need to select a datum corresponding to an input value when that value exists in a table, and to instead select a static default value when it does not. The best way I could find to accomplish this was to write something like this:

```
SELECT desired_datum
FROM (
    --Try to get explicit datum
    SELECT desired_datum, 1 AS was_found
    FROM data_table
    WHERE the_key = &input_value
    UNION
    --Get default datum
    SELECT 'default' AS desired_datum, 0 AS was_found
    FROM dual
    --Put explicit datum on top, if it exists
    ORDER BY was_found DESC
) finder
WHERE ROWNUM <=1;
```

It seems like there must be some idiomatic way to do this which doesn't depend on this strange use of `ORDER BY`, but I couldn't find it. Does anyone know of any better methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a simpler version of what you did:

```
SELECT NVL(desired_datum, 'default') AS desired_datum
FROM DUAL LEFT JOIN  data_table ON the_key = &input_value
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(desired_datum), 'default')
FROM data_table
WHERE the_key = &input_value
```