# If the result set is empty, fill in basic values

Tags: sql

If the result set of a query is empty, I want to force a specific result.

When I use the query below, I only get answers when there are results.

If the result is not there I want the query to return via the asked field (`@ProductheaderdoscodeBOM`) the result 'NONE'

See the query:

```
USE [DM]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SIP_rpt_R9000_PD_BOM]    Script Date:     08/26/2014 11:04:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SIP_rpt_R9000_PD_BOM]
     @ProdHeaderDossierCode T_Code_ProdHeadDossier = NULL,
     @ProductheaderdoscodeBOM T_Code_ProdHeadDossier = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @ProductheaderdoscodeBOM=PHPL.ProdHeaderDossierCode 
    FROM T_ProdHeadProdBomLink as PHPL
    WHERE PHPL.ProdBOMProdHeaderDossierCode=@ProdHeaderDossierCode
    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    SET @ProductheaderdoscodeBOM='NONE'
    SELECT @ProductheaderdoscodeBOM
    FROM T_ProdHeadProdBomLink as PHPL
    WHERE PHPL.ProdBOMProdHeaderDossierCode=@ProdHeaderDossierCode
    RETURN 0
END`
```

Comment: see similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427990

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just want to return `'NONE'` when the first query returns no rows.  I think this logic will do what you want:

```
select @ProductheaderdoscodeBOM = PHPL.ProdHeaderDossierCode 
FROM T_ProdHeadProdBomLink as PHPL
WHERE PHPL.ProdBOMProdHeaderDossierCode = @ProdHeaderDossierCode;

if @@ROWCOUNT = 0 begin
    set @ProductheaderdoscodeBOM = 'NONE';
end;

select @ProductheaderdoscodeBOM;
return 0;
```

In other words, you don't need to repeat the query.

By the way, you could also do this without the `if`:

```
select @ProductheaderdoscodeBOM = coalesce(max(PHPL.ProdHeaderDossierCode), 'NONE')
FROM T_ProdHeadProdBomLink as PHPL
WHERE PHPL.ProdBOMProdHeaderDossierCode = @ProdHeaderDossierCode;

select @ProductheaderdoscodeBOM;
```

Comment: Not sure the second query will work, when assigning a value using `SELECT @Variable = Column`, if there are no rows that match there will be no assignment, rather than assigning `NULL`, so it won't be assigned the second argument of the coalesce function. In this example: `DECLARE @v VARCHAR(5) = 'TEST1'; SELECT @v = COALESCE(C, 'NONE') FROM (VALUES ('TEST2')) t(C) WHERE t.C = @v; SELECT @V;` @V will still retain it's original value of `'TEST1'`, not `'NONE'`. The first method will work though, so have upvoted for that.

Comment: @GarethD . . . It worked in my head.  I really had a `MAX()` there when I was *thinking* about the problem, but it clearly didn't make it to my fingers.  I just added it in.