# t-sql forcing a message when nothing is returned. using CTE and CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am pulling back some data that is going to be used in some reporting. Most times this will return no data, when there is no data being returned I want the end user to see a message, and when there is data i want to return the data element and different message. I will not include the CTE portion just the CASE.  it should be enough.  I am not sure why this is not working, it should be a simple CASE.

```
SELECT Case when Sum(1) IS NULL  THEN 
    'NO DUPES MISSING INFO'
ELSE 
        CTE.ClaimNum + ' Claim is missing, Please populate'  
END AS MissingClaiminfo

FROM CTE

WHERE ClaimCheck > 0
OR CLAIMFormatCk > 0
OR CLAIMIdCheck > 0
OR CLAIM_DupID_Match > 0
Group by CTE.ClaimNum
```

What returns is no record or message for MissingClaimInfo.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT --- ENTIRE QUERY BELOW:

```
WITH Nasco_CTE (
                    CoClaimNum
                    ,ClaimNum
                    ,ClaimCheck
                    ,CLAIMFormatCk
                    ,CLAIMIdCheck
                    ,CLAIMID_DupID_Match
                )

AS
    (

        SELECT

             CW.User047 AS CoClaimNum
            ,CW.ClaimNum AS ClaimNum
            ,CASE WHEN Left(CW.User047,1) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As ClaimCheck  --     Checks for leading zeroes. 
            ,CASE WHEN SubString(CW.User047,LEN(LEFT(CW.User047, CharIndex('-    ',CW.User047) )),1) <> '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CLAIMFormatCk   --- Checks for '-'
            ,CASE WHEN NASC.NascoClaimId = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CLAIMIdCheck
            ,CASE WHEN NASC.NascoClaimId <> ECW.NascoClaimId THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS     CLAIMID_DupID_Match

        FROM Screens.dbo.vClaimsWHSE CW
        LEFT JOIN [Screens].dbo.[vClaimsWHSE_RootReason] CWRR
            ON CW.ClaimCode = CWRR.Reason
        LEFT JOIN [Support].[dbo].[NascoDupID_Crosswalk] NASC
            ON  NASC.ClaimNum = SUBSTRING(CW.User047,0,CHARINDEX('-',CW.[User047]))
            AND NASC.LineSequenceNum =  SUBSTRING(CW.User047,CHARINDEX('-',CW.     [User047])+1,CHARINDEX('-',CW.[User047]))
        LEFT JOIN [Data].[dbo].[ExportCrosswalk] ECW
            ON CW.User001 = ECW.ClaimNum 
            AND CW.User002 = ECW.LineSequenceNum
        WHERE CW.user003 IN ('NC','RevRecon') 
            And NASC.ClaimId IS NOT NULL
    )


SELECT Case when COUNT(Nasco_CTE.ClaimNum) =''  THEN 
     'NO DUPES MISSING INFO'
ELSE 
     Nasco_CTE.ClaimNum + ' Claim is missing a DupNascoID.  Please check check that     USER047 is populated correctly: ClaimNum-LineNum EX: 020132952416600-1'  
END AS MissingNascoId 
FROM Nasco_CTE

WHERE ClaimCheck > 0
OR ClaimCheck > 0
OR CLAIMIdCheck > 0
OR CLAIMID_DupID_Match > 0
Group by Nasco_CTE.ClaimNum
```

Note the code works when I remove Nasco_CTE.ClaimNum +  from the ELSE Section. and remove the group by.

Comment: Why are you doing Sum(1)? That will never be null, thus your else will always execute.  If CTE.ClaimNum is null then you will get null for your MissingClaimInfo field.

Comment: True, I am attempting to test if there are records being returned. so a sum(1) would not give me what I am looking for.  Possibly a count of the records?

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427990/oracle-11g-default-to-static-value-when-query-returns-nothing/25428156#25428156 you just need to create DUAL table with one record to make it work.

Comment: Could you post you entire query, some sample data and the desired output?  That will make it much easier to figure out what you are dealing with and what will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a couple more CTEs:

```
;WITH Nasco_CTE (/* Columns */)

AS
    (/* Definition */
), InitialResults as (
    SELECT CTE.ClaimNum + ' Claim is missing, Please populate'  
      AS MissingClaiminfo, 0 as Ord

   FROM CTE

   WHERE ClaimCheck > 0
   OR CLAIMFormatCk > 0
   OR CLAIMIdCheck > 0
   OR CLAIM_DupID_Match > 0
   Group by CTE.ClaimNum --This might not be needed any more, I think
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'NO DUPES MISSING INFO',1
), Ranked as (
    SELECT *,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Ord) as rk
)
SELECT * from Ranked where rk = 1
```

Which will only produce the row which had `Ord` `1` if there are no rows with `Ord` equal to `0` - and thus you either get your desired result set *or* the single row saying `NO DUPES MISSING INFO`.

---

You can generally use the above (`UNION ALL` and numbering the result sets) technique where:

- You just want one result set if it contains any results
- if the first result set contains zero results, you want a *different* result set
- the second result set (and any others, this idea can be extended) is compatible with the first result set
- the second result set (and others) is cheap to compute so you don't mind computing it anyway

Answer (score 0):

Brian, Can we follow a pattern like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Statement..)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'NO DUPES MISSING INFO'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT ... FROM CTE WHERE ...
END
```

Comment: Interesting Idea, Let me play with it and see if I can get it to work. I will let you know