# Return result from query even if WHERE clause not met

Tags: sql, sql-server, ibatis.net

I am creating a query that ensures some constraints are met. Here's a semi-working version right now:

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN TaskId IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 1  
        END AS TaskExists, 
        CASE
            WHEN IsDownTask = 0 AND TaskStatus = 63 THEN 1
            WHEN IsDownTask = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS PressReady,
        CASE 
            WHEN IsDownTask = 1 AND MachineId <> 2710 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS DownTaskAssignedToDifferentMachine   
FROM Task T
WHERE TaskId = 555555
```

This works fine when `TaskId` exists in the `Task` table, but I also need to return values if that Task doesn't exist (hence the `TaskExists` field).

For a query on a non-existent Task, I'd expect to return

- TaskExists 0
- PressReady 0
- DownTaskAssignedToDisfferentMachine 0

How can I modify my query to return this even when no `TaskId` exists?

Comment: When the `taskId` does not exists in this table where else it is existing?

Comment: This could be done using perhaps a pretty ugly SQL statement. If I were you, I'd just leave the SQL like this and implement a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) on the C# side that has the attributes you enumerated. I would use the null object in case the SQL returns no result

Comment: Is TaskId unique in this table?

Comment: TaskId is coming from user input. If they fat-finger something I want to make sure that I can provide some feedback that we don't know about the Task. TaskId is unique in the Task table, yes. I am leaning more towards querying for the Task object and checking if null and the remaining properties on the client side now...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle 11g: Default to static value when query returns nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427990/oracle-11g-default-to-static-value-when-query-returns-nothing)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to return those values just wrap each column with a `SUM` and an `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE
        WHEN TaskId IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1  
    END), 0) AS TaskExists, 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE
        WHEN IsDownTask = 0 AND TaskStatus = 63 THEN 1
        WHEN IsDownTask = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END), 0) AS PressReady,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE 
        WHEN IsDownTask = 1 AND MachineId <> 2710 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END), 0) AS DownTaskAssignedToDifferentMachine
```

Comment: I would just use `count(TaskId)` for `TaskExists`.

Comment: Count would work too and would let us eliminate the case expression too. Good idea.

Comment: Yeah, this works just as I want. I suggested an edit to add `ISNULL` checks to the last two fields. Otherwise they return `NULL` and I want to avoid having to return nullable ints from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @task INT
SET @task = 555555

SELECT CASE
            WHEN TaskId IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 1  
        END AS TaskExists, 
        CASE
            WHEN IsDownTask = 0 AND TaskStatus = 63 THEN 1
            WHEN IsDownTask = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS PressReady,
        CASE 
            WHEN IsDownTask = 1 AND MachineId <> 2710 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS DownTaskAssignedToDifferentMachine   
FROM Task T
WHERE TaskId = @task
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0 TaskExists, 0 PressReady, 0 DownTaskAssignedToDifferentMachine   
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  Task WHERE TaskId = @task)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it must be in a query, rather than in the code, then just cheat and tack the default row on to the end of your query.  Guarantee that the default sorts after any possible veritable result, and limit to your first row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS TaskExists, CASE ... END AS PressReady, CASE ... AS WowYouHaveALongFieldNameHere
    FROM Task
   WHERE TaskID = 55555

  UNION

  -- default if no matching row
  SELECT 0,               0,                          0
) ORDER BY TaskExists DESC;
```

You may find this more readable than alternatives involving aggregate functions or forcing a join and COALESCE/ISNULLing, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code. I haven't tested.

```
SELECT CASE
                WHEN TaskId IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE 1  
            END AS TaskExists, 
            CASE
                WHEN IsDownTask = 0 AND TaskStatus = 63 THEN 1
                WHEN IsDownTask = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS PressReady,
            CASE 
                WHEN IsDownTask = 1 AND MachineId <> 2710 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS DownTaskAssignedToDifferentMachine   
    FROM Task T
    WHERE  1= case when TaskId = 555555 then 1 
    else 0 end
```

Comment: Suggested an edit to this: your ELSE was an 'o' instead of zero.  It's good that you flagged it as untested, but in future it might be worth taking the extra time to test your answers first before posting them - a higher-quality answer, even a few minutes late, is by far better to posting something with an issue.